# Run test plan against 3rd party versioned programs

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio Online I created a test plan for a program that was written by a different company that my company uses. We have a specific set of tests that need to be tested before we accept a new version of this program. So when I edit the test plan I would like to be able to manually select a build by typing in say version "1.0.1.195". Then when a newer version comes out I can just type in a newer version and retest using those same tests. However when I go to select a build TFS is filtering against my builds for my code. Is it possible to do what I'm asking using TFS?

**EDIT**

To answer a few of the questions in the comments I'll be a bit more descriptive of what I am doing. A 3rd party company made a program we use to test some hardware. Every now and then there is an update to that software. Since a few of us use this program to test out the hardware we need to know that the software can be installed with little to no down time while upgrading. So we came up with a small set of tests that we run the program through to make sure that we can test reliably. Those tests were written in a Word document, so I put them into MTM. Although I make some software that is related to this their software depends on mine. I've not had to update my code for some time now. My overall intention is to use MTM to document my testing of this program.

> Do you want to store the version of the 3rd party component along with the test result of the test run it was tested with on TFS?

That would be nice. My ultimate end game is to put the results of said test back into that Word Document and make that available to those who don't have MTM installed (which is everyone). This way when a new version of the software is updated I can just go into MTM reset all my tests back to active update the version number and retest.

Comment: Do you have source code of this 3rd party program and so you have to build it? Or is it a dll referenced by your code?

Comment: @Elena it is referenced by my code

Comment: Some more questions. Do you have to rebuild your application before testing new version of 3rd party component? Is the implementation of your tests build using the same build definition you are using to build the productive code? What is your intention exactly? Do you want to store the version of the 3rd party component along with the test result of the test run it was tested with on TFS? if so is it essential for you to be able to see this version in "plain text" using *MTM*? Or would it be sufficient to have a possibility to get this version another way (e.g. making several mouse clicks)?

Comment: Are you running automated tests using MTM?

Comment: @Elena No I am not running automated tests (wish I was). The 3rd party software is a program that uses my library. My library is no longer in development... I think i'm going to answer the rest of your questions in a edit to my post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45258/discussion-between-elena-and-robert-snyder)

Answer (score 0):

The build you set up in *Microsoft Test Manager* (MTM) defines where is the drop location containing your **tests**, not the application under test (it can be different if you build your tests using another build).

That's why you only can select one of your builds for your code.

What you are talking about is deployment.
That means you have to make sure the right version of the 3rd party program is deployed to the environment the tests are running on.

**EDIT**

What you need is a *Test Configuration*
Here you can find a is a good explanation how to create one: [Test Configurations - specifying test platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286643%28VS.110%29.aspx)

The idea in your use case would be as following
*(below I'm using terms described in the article mentioned above):*

1. Create a *Configuration Variable* where you will store the current version of the 3rd party program
2. Create a *Test Configuration* and add this variable to it.
3. Set this *Test Configuration* as default test configuration for your test plan.
   *Be aware, if your test plan already contains test cases you will have to add this Test Configuration to each Test Case manually since only new added Test Cases get it assigned automatically*

If you get a new version of the 3rd party program you will:

1. **Add** the new version of the program to the values allowed for the *Configuration Variable*
2. Open the *Test Configuration* you are using and update the program's version to the new one.
3. Reset your tests and run them.

Doing so you:

- store all versions you have tested so far in the *Configuration Variable* since you add the new one instead of overwrite the old one, so you get a kind of history.
- store the last version you have tested in the *Test Configuration*.

That should meet you needs.

**Additional suggestion**
*(has nothing to do with your question but with your use case)*

Consider describing tests within your *Test Cases* instead of creating a *Word* document.
Here is a good place to start reading: [How to: Create a Manual Test Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286659%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The benefits would be:

1. You can run your manual tests using *Test Runner* provided by *MTM*
   Doing so you will have all steps you have done stored by the *Test Result*, you can add comments to each step when executing that, etc.
2. You can still export the test description to a *Word* document using this *MTM* add-on: [Test Scribe](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e2c743ce-d9f1-4ed0-ab08-a4777bef06a4).
   Using this add-on you can also create a report of your test execution.

Additionally, if you are going to use *MTM* more in your daily job I would recommend you this free e-book [Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380)